# Is there a way to make react-compound-timer Auto-reset when it hits a value without pressing any buttons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-compound-timer

So here is some example code that I have written up, all I want for the functionality of this timer is to reach a checkpoint, which is zero, and than it calls a function. But, once it hits 0, I am trying to make it so auto-reset without any button clicks whatsoever.

```html
  <td>Time Left in Interval:  </td>
    <td><Timer
        checkpoints={[ {time: 0, callback:() => handleOpen()}]}
        lastUnit={"s"}
        initialTime={that.state.timeInterval * 1000}
        direction="backward"
    >
        <Timer.Seconds />  seconds

    </Timer></td>
```

I have looked into react-compound-timer and they have an example with buttons. Just wondering if I can get the same affect without those, i.e. when the timer hits zero, the timer resets back to the initial time variable and it will call the function "handleOpen()". handleOpen() is a function to open a simpleModal from Material UI. InitialTime is a variable that gets passed through react router, everything is handled in state in App.js. So I pass that={this}... so essentially that=this.

```html
<Timer
    initialTime={55000}
>
    {({ start, resume, pause, stop, reset, timerState }) => (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div>
                <Timer.Days /> days
                <Timer.Hours /> hours
                <Timer.Minutes /> minutes
                <Timer.Seconds /> seconds
                <Timer.Milliseconds /> milliseconds
            </div>
            <div>{timerState}</div>
            <br />
            <div>
                <button onClick={start}>Start</button>
                <button onClick={pause}>Pause</button>
                <button onClick={resume}>Resume</button>
                <button onClick={stop}>Stop</button>
                <button onClick={reset}>Reset</button>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )}
</Timer>
```

This is an example of resetting react-compound-timer with a button
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-compound-timer

Answer (score 1):

you can use React.createRef to get instance of Timer and reset it

```js
const tiRef = React.createRef();
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Timer
    initialTime={5000}
    direction="backward"
    ref={tiRef}
    checkpoints={[
      {
          time: 0,
          callback: function (e) { tiRef.current.reset()},
      }
  ]}
>
```

Comment: So it seems like it reset, but the timer doesn't auto-restart for me. Like in your example, It will countdown from 5 seconds initially, when it reaches 0, the timer will go back to 5 seconds. But then it just stays at 5 seconds and doesn't decrement further. Also thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Actually, I got it figured out!! Thank you! :). I added tiRef.current.start() into the call back function